# Need pass dynamic url param value in button url of ui-component grid

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I have a button on a admin grid in Magento 2 which need to pass URL parameter coming on the grid page like:

```
http://127.0.0.1/admin/vendor_module/questionsetflow/index/questionset_id/19/key/8a93789d2ff74e19ee9d8b0aabc1349419582836dea63df961a6146d7454cf38/
```

[image]

I need to pass the dynamic param questionset_id (value = 19) to button 'Add New Question' in my admin grid (ui component):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">alkemy_chatbot_questionsetflow_listing.alkemy_chatbot_questionsetflow_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">alkemy_chatbot_questionsetflow_listing.alkemy_chatbot_questionsetflow_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">alkemy_chatbot_questionsetflow_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">back</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Back</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">alkemy_chatbot/questionset/index</item>
            </item>
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Question</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="alkemy_chatbot/questionsetflow/new">
                    <param name="questionset_id">!!!!!!!!</param>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

What value is necessary to put in `<param name="questionset_id">`

Thanks

Comment: Did you solved the above one?

Answer (score 3):

[Use button like here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml#L15)

And then add following line inside buttons tag

```
<button name="custom_button_name" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomButton"/>
```

**Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/CustomButton.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * CustomButton constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'id' => 'custom-button',
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('*/*/url', ['id' => 2])),
            'sort_order' => 20,
        ];
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```